# Docker logs lost after system reboot when using local file logging driver

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to start my service and switched to [local](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/local/) driver by adding

```
    logging:
      driver: local
```

in all the services. It seems that after a system reboot, the logs are not available anymore if using `docker logs <container>` command. Is this an expected behavior, if yes, is there a way to persist them across system reboot?

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-logs-lost-after-system-reboot-when-using-local-file-logging-driver/120255